# Hippo custom essential plugin creation

Tags: content-management-system, hippocms

How do we add our own plugin. Lets say a new add-on or feature which can be installed and used. How do we develop that? I am sorry i am new to this.
Kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your needs, I suggest you check out:
https://documentation.bloomreach.com/14/library/concepts/open-ui/introduction.html

You can also create various plugins more like the native functionality. Adding such to essentials is described here:
https://documentation.bloomreach.com/14/library/essentials-plugins/overview.html

That doesn't tell you how to create a plugin however. Essentials is just a helper application, the plugin can be various things from services, to configuration, to document types, to hst components... All of that requires some knowledge of the internals of the system. Look around the documentation, you can see how to create various things like workflows, perspectives, and more.

A plugin is no more than a collection of code and configuration bundled together. It could be a frontend thing or a backend thing. So I can't simply tell you how to create them. It can be quite difficult, depending on what you want, to create a plugin. Look into the code of some plugins, you will see that it is basically a java project with some configuration that can be found by the system on startup.

You might want to ask more specifically on what exactly you want to develop. That could lead to more specific advice. It can be daunting when you are starting to work with the cms. With experience it does start to make sense.